# Capture or supress trackback from exception raised by module

Tags: python, paramiko

In the code below, it still prints trackback from one specific exception even though it's caught with try/except. I'm not sure why.

If there is any exception raised with the SSH connection the code continues and simply informs of the failure. This works as expected except in one secnario.

Someitmes, for network reasons outside of my control, the paramiko module get's a socket.timeout exception. This exception gets caught by the try except block as expected but the trackback still get's dumped to the console. Noteably the trackback contains both the socket.timeout and SSHException text which is usually not printed.

I would like to catch this trackback in a variable for logging or simply surpress it instead of buggering the output.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy, SSHException


def test_ssh_login (host_info, sshport = 22):
    test_passed = False
    try:                                                                                                            
        client = SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(host_info['host'], username = host_info['user'], password = host_info['pass'], port = sshport )
    except:
        print(f"[failed] ssh {host_info['user']}@{host_info['host']} port: {sshport} using password : {host_info['pass']}")
        return False

    else:
        if client.get_transport() is not None:
            if client.get_transport().is_authenticated():
                test_passed = True                                                                                              finally:
        client.close()
        return test_passed


test_host_info = {'host': '192.168.0.1', 'user': 'username', 'pass': "SomePassword"}

if (test_ssh_login(test_host_info)):
    print(f"successful connection with { test_host_info }")
```

The code works as desired and the cause of the timeout is not really a concern.

Just wondering why the text comes to the console for this exctption and no others.

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Code/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
  File "/home/user/Code/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/user/Code/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 622, in _read_timeout
    raise socket.timeout()                                                                                                  socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Code/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2039, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "/home/user/Code/Python/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2215, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

Comment: I don't have it atm. I will try and reproduce it but I'm still not sure what triggers the timeout. The code works most of the time as expected excected. 
I'm not concerned with the cause of the timeouts.

Why if an exception is caught in a try block, so as not to terminate the program does the trackback still get dumped to the console?

Comment: added the trackback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

I needed to catch both the SSHexception and an addional EOFError and throw them both to the log.

```
try:
                # connect
        client.connect(host_info['host'], username = host_info['user'], password = host_info['pass'], port = sshport )
    except socket.timeout:
        print("[Socket Timeout]")
    except Exception:
        print(f"[failed] ssh {host_info['user']}@{host_info['host']} port: {sshport} using password : {host_info['pass']}")
    except EOFerror:
        pass
```